# Tomcat and web services

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, tomcat6

Hello I have a set of web services made in JAVA that are made using a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse. 
When i run an instance of Tomcat 6 in Eclipse and deploy the project on the server it works just fine, I am able to find the wsdl File and access it from a php script.

But when I export the Dynamic Web Proyect as a WAR file and deploy it on the webapps file inside the real Tomcat server, and start the server, I have no idea how to find the wsdl file or how to access it from my php scripts, its just not working.

Is there any thing i have to do to get this to work?

Comment: Do you see anything in the Tomcat console? Do you see error messages when you start the real server? Have you tried to re-download Tomcat?

Comment: What URL are you going to, what is the name of the war, what is your context root?

Comment: Thx my tomcat had something wrong i re download it and now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to re-download Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

If you generate dynamic wsdl then . you can find it at URL something like

http://example.com/context/demo.wsdl

It will be easy to answer your questing if you post web.xml and other related xml config file.